# In hapi.js what is the difference between an Auth Scheme and Strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, authorization, hapi.js

The [**hapi.js**](http://hapijs.com/api#server) documentation is not *especially* (*complete*) beginner-friendly<sup>1</sup> ...

What is the *distinction* between a Server Auth [***Scheme***](http://hapijs.com/api#serverauthschemename-scheme) and [***Strategy***](http://hapijs.com/api#serverauthstrategyname-scheme-mode-options)?

Do we need to have *both*?

<sup>1</sup>If someone can *explain* the difference we will PR into the docs.

Also posted on: https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/163

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you need both. They're different things entirely. They're explained here: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth. But let me rehash that differently:

**SCHEMES**

A scheme is a general type of authentication. Basic authentication and Digest authentication are different types of authentication, and in hapi each would be a different scheme. You can think of a scheme as a template for authentication. A scheme isn’t used directly to authenticate users, instead you create a specific strategy from the scheme.

**STRATEGIES**

A strategy is a configured instance of a scheme with an assigned name. Strategies exist so you can use the same scheme several times, in a slightly different way. For instance, might decide to you want use basic authentication in your app. For some routes you might wish to validate a user’s passwords against a value in a database and for some other routes, you might wish to check the password against a value stored in a text file. In this case you can create 2 different strategies from the scheme. The scheme to strategy relationship is described visually below:

[image]

Most applications will create new strategies from pre-existing schemes that have been released as plugins (i.e. [hapi-auth-basic](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic)).